# How to create a sub group under a main head?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-api

I want to include some points under a main head like groups in pivot table. There will be a plus sign in a box beside the main head. And when i click the plus sign beside the main head, sub points will be opened as drop down.

I am trying to do it on excel 2016 and google spreadsheet. But unfortunately I can't execute it. Any idea or any process to execute it ???
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example right out of the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getUi()).

```
function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('My Menu')
       .addItem('My menu item', 'myFunction')
       .addSeparator()
       .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My sub-menu')
           .addItem('One sub-menu item', 'mySecondFunction')
           .addItem('Another sub-menu item', 'myThirdFunction'))
       .addToUi();
 }
```